# Android - a Thread is crushing the application

Tags: android, multithreading

I created a simple application.

When the user touchs the "Start .." button, it shows a "loading animation" on the button label.

I created application on my PC (e.g. desktop application) , and it works great.

the Android's application code:

```
package com.example.threaddot;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    SeekBar pointSpeed, numPoint;
    Button startButton, detailsButton;
    Thread count;
    boolean started = false;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // my vars
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_start);
        detailsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_details);
        numPoint = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar_numpoints);
        pointSpeed = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.PointSpeedSeekBar);

        count = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                setDots();
            }
        });

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count.start();
            }
        });

        detailsButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showAlert("Info",
                        String.format("Current: %s, %d points, and shown per %d m/s.", !started ? "working" : "suspend", 
                                numPoint.getProgress(), pointSpeed.getProgress()));             
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void setDots() {
        int counter = 0, numPoints = numPoint.getProgress();
        while(true) {
            if(counter++ < 10) {
                startButton.setText(startButton.getText() + ".  ");
            }

            else {
                counter = 0;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }           
    }

    void showAlert(String title, String msg) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog;
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);
        alertDialog.setMessage(msg);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

When I press the "Start .." button, it's crushes.

In other words,

```
startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count.start();
        }
    });
```

Crashing the application. why?

Logcat:

```
01-18 20:07:43.453: W/dalvikvm(29186): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
01-18 20:07:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(29186): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11
01-18 20:07:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(29186): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
01-18 20:07:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(29186):    at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:3055)
01-18 20:07:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(29186):    at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:649)
01-18 20:07:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(29186):    at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:675)
01-18 20:07:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(29186):    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2511)
01-18 20:07:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(29186):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5279)
01-18 20:07:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(29186):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:5782)
01-18 20:07:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(29186):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2824)
01-18 20:07:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(29186):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2685)
01-18 20:07:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(29186):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2654)
01-18 20:07:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(29186):    at com.example.threaddot.MainActivity.setDots(MainActivity.java:66)
01-18 20:07:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(29186):    at com.example.threaddot.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:32)
01-18 20:07:43.500: E/AndroidRuntime(29186):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
01-18 20:10:49.632: W/ActivityThread(29426): Application com.example.threaddot is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
01-18 20:10:49.648: I/System.out(29426): Sending WAIT chunk
01-18 20:10:49.859: I/System.out(29426): Debugger has connected
01-18 20:10:49.859: I/System.out(29426): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:10:50.054: I/System.out(29426): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:10:50.257: I/System.out(29426): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:10:50.460: I/System.out(29426): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:10:50.664: I/System.out(29426): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:10:50.867: I/System.out(29426): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:10:51.062: I/System.out(29426): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:10:51.265: I/System.out(29426): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:10:51.468: I/System.out(29426): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:10:51.671: I/System.out(29426): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:10:51.875: I/System.out(29426): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:10:52.085: I/System.out(29426): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:10:52.281: I/System.out(29426): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:10:52.500: I/System.out(29426): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:10:52.695: I/System.out(29426): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:10:52.898: I/System.out(29426): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:10:53.101: I/System.out(29426): debugger has settled (1476)
01-18 20:12:48.117: W/dalvikvm(29426): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
01-18 20:12:48.195: E/AndroidRuntime(29426): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
01-18 20:12:48.195: E/AndroidRuntime(29426): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
01-18 20:12:48.195: E/AndroidRuntime(29426):    at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:3055)
01-18 20:12:48.195: E/AndroidRuntime(29426):    at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:649)
01-18 20:12:48.195: E/AndroidRuntime(29426):    at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:675)
01-18 20:12:48.195: E/AndroidRuntime(29426):    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2511)
01-18 20:12:48.195: E/AndroidRuntime(29426):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5279)
01-18 20:12:48.195: E/AndroidRuntime(29426):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:5782)
01-18 20:12:48.195: E/AndroidRuntime(29426):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2824)
01-18 20:12:48.195: E/AndroidRuntime(29426):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2685)
01-18 20:12:48.195: E/AndroidRuntime(29426):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2654)
01-18 20:12:48.195: E/AndroidRuntime(29426):    at com.example.threaddot.MainActivity.setDots(MainActivity.java:66)
01-18 20:12:48.195: E/AndroidRuntime(29426):    at com.example.threaddot.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:32)
01-18 20:12:48.195: E/AndroidRuntime(29426):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
01-18 20:14:52.031: D/AndroidRuntime(29761): Shutting down VM
01-18 20:14:52.031: W/dalvikvm(29761): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
01-18 20:14:52.062: E/AndroidRuntime(29761): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 20:14:52.062: E/AndroidRuntime(29761): java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.
01-18 20:14:52.062: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1227)
01-18 20:14:52.062: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at com.example.threaddot.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:40)
01-18 20:14:52.062: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
01-18 20:14:52.062: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
01-18 20:14:52.062: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-18 20:14:52.062: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-18 20:14:52.062: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-18 20:14:52.062: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-18 20:14:52.062: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 20:14:52.062: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-18 20:14:52.062: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
01-18 20:14:52.062: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
01-18 20:14:52.062: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-18 20:15:35.492: W/ActivityThread(29953): Application com.example.threaddot is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
01-18 20:15:35.734: I/System.out(29953): Sending WAIT chunk
01-18 20:15:35.937: I/System.out(29953): Debugger has connected
01-18 20:15:35.937: I/System.out(29953): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:15:36.140: I/System.out(29953): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:15:36.343: I/System.out(29953): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:15:36.546: I/System.out(29953): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:15:36.742: I/System.out(29953): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:15:36.945: I/System.out(29953): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:15:37.148: I/System.out(29953): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:15:37.359: I/System.out(29953): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:15:37.554: I/System.out(29953): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:15:37.757: I/System.out(29953): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:15:37.960: I/System.out(29953): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:15:38.164: I/System.out(29953): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 20:15:38.367: I/System.out(29953): debugger has settled (1495)
01-18 20:16:13.609: W/dalvikvm(29953): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
01-18 20:16:13.679: E/AndroidRuntime(29953): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
01-18 20:16:13.679: E/AndroidRuntime(29953): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
01-18 20:16:13.679: E/AndroidRuntime(29953):    at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:3055)
01-18 20:16:13.679: E/AndroidRuntime(29953):    at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:649)
01-18 20:16:13.679: E/AndroidRuntime(29953):    at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:675)
01-18 20:16:13.679: E/AndroidRuntime(29953):    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2511)
01-18 20:16:13.679: E/AndroidRuntime(29953):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5279)
01-18 20:16:13.679: E/AndroidRuntime(29953):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:5782)
01-18 20:16:13.679: E/AndroidRuntime(29953):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2824)
01-18 20:16:13.679: E/AndroidRuntime(29953):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2685)
01-18 20:16:13.679: E/AndroidRuntime(29953):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2654)
01-18 20:16:13.679: E/AndroidRuntime(29953):    at com.example.threaddot.MainActivity.setDots(MainActivity.java:66)
01-18 20:16:13.679: E/AndroidRuntime(29953):    at com.example.threaddot.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:32)
01-18 20:16:13.679: E/AndroidRuntime(29953):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
01-18 20:21:29.492: D/AndroidRuntime(30489): Shutting down VM
01-18 20:21:29.492: W/dalvikvm(30489): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
01-18 20:21:29.632: E/AndroidRuntime(30489): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 20:21:29.632: E/AndroidRuntime(30489): java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.
01-18 20:21:29.632: E/AndroidRuntime(30489):    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1227)
01-18 20:21:29.632: E/AndroidRuntime(30489):    at com.example.threaddot.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:40)
01-18 20:21:29.632: E/AndroidRuntime(30489):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
01-18 20:21:29.632: E/AndroidRuntime(30489):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
01-18 20:21:29.632: E/AndroidRuntime(30489):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-18 20:21:29.632: E/AndroidRuntime(30489):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-18 20:21:29.632: E/AndroidRuntime(30489):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-18 20:21:29.632: E/AndroidRuntime(30489):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-18 20:21:29.632: E/AndroidRuntime(30489):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 20:21:29.632: E/AndroidRuntime(30489):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-18 20:21:29.632: E/AndroidRuntime(30489):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
01-18 20:21:29.632: E/AndroidRuntime(30489):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
01-18 20:21:29.632: E/AndroidRuntime(30489):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Could you please post the stack trace from LogCat?

Comment: @EJK of course. do it right now.

Comment: The answer below is right on.  As the stack trace indicates, you cannot touch UI elements in a non-UI thread.  That is what caused the exception.

Comment: @EJK His suggestion stucking my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as in log :

> CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created
>   a view hierarchy can touch its views.

means you will need to [runOnUiThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) for updating to accessing Ui elements from Thread as:

```
   MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // update textview here

        }
    });
```

Change your setDots() method as :

```
public void setDots() {
        int counter = 0, numPoints =0;
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                    numPoints = numPoint.getProgress();
                 }
               });
          while(true) {
            if(counter++ < 10) {
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                     startButton.setText(startButton.getText() + ".  ");
                 }
               });
            }

            else {
                counter = 0;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }           
    }
```

Comment: @user1798362 : you also need to put `numPoints = numPoint.getProgress();` line inside runOnUiThread

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify anything dealing with the UI on any thread but the "main" thread. You should look at using an AsyncTask which has the ability to periodically report information and update upon completion. The "quick and dirty" way is to create a handler (It must be created on the UI thread, so initialized as an instance variable of your activity or on oncreate,onXXX, etc) and have it post to the UI thread when you need to update.

This has to be created on the UI thread.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

This handler can be passed to your background thread and post updates like so:

```
handler.post(new Runnable()
{
    public void run() {
    //UI UPDATES HERE.
    }
});
```

You should really read through the android documentation, it's thorough and covers all this in great detail.

Comment: still stucking. it seems it run on the main thread instead of new thread